# Как подтянуть изменения из другой ветки?

Tags: git, git-branch

К примеру, у меня есть ветка feature-1, и я сделал feature-2, унаследовав от первой ветки (feature1 -> feature2).
После этого начал работать на второй ветке, однако, спустя время, потребовалось внести изменения в первой ветке.

Как мне применить изменения, которые я сделал в первой ветке для второй?

Comment: если комитов в первой ветке много, то смотрите в сторону rebase, если один, то cherry pick.

Comment: Может быть `git checkout feature2`, `git merge feature1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если коммиты, добавленные во вторую ветку, ещё никуда не отправлялись, то самое подходящее средство — это `rebase`:

```
$ git checkout feature-2
$ git rebase feature-1
```

при этом коммиты, которые добавлены в ветку `feature-2`, будут пересозданы «поверх» того коммита, на который указывает указатель `feature-1` («ветка» в git — это ведь просто плавающий указатель на коммит).

---

доп. чтение:

```
$ man git-rebase
```